# Is it possible to know where pop will take you before executing?

Tags: dart, flutter

I would like to achieve the following logic:

```dart
Future<bool> _onWillPop() async {
  // If (pop.location == some screen)
  // then more logic

  // else:
  return Future.value(true);
}
```

I cannot figure out how to know the destination of where a `Navigator.pop` will take my user.

Comment: you can use `popAndPushNamed` read more in this article: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-push-pop-push-1bb718b13c31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not know where a `pop` will take you unless you manually track it.

This means that you will have to observe pushing routes. There are many ways to achieve this, e.g. just storing a global variable.

However, there is an easy way to *track **which routes** are being tracked*: **[`RouteObserver`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/RouteObserver-class.html)**
The documentation should be sufficient to implement this.